# Convert Keys in an array to Lower case & remove spaces between keys if available (JS)

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I need to convert Keys into lowercases and remove the spaces between them if any. **All the keys are Dynamic** and could be any number of keys. Keys might contain alphanumeric along with special characters.Javascript or Typescript anything would do for me. I'm little stuck here.

Current JSON :

```
[
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label1",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label2",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value2"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label3",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value3"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label4",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value4"
    }
  ]
```

Expected JSON :

```
 [
    {
      "outdatedlabel(key1)": "Outdated Label1",
      "outdatedvalue": "Outdated Value"
    },
    {
      "outdatedlabel(key1)": "Outdated Label2",
      "outdatedvalue": "Outdated Value2"
    },
    {
      "outdatedlabel(key1)": "Outdated Label3",
      "outdatedvalue": "Outdated Value3"
    },
    {
      "outdatedlabel(key1)": "Outdated Label4",
      "outdatedvalue": "Outdated Value4"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at the problem and came up with a solution that works and is written in plain JavaScript. This solution works for the given array and any other array of objects that are not nested.
As you want to have a new array we can use .map and then iterate over every key in the current object and modify the key in such a way that it satisfies your requirements.

```
let o = [
  {
    "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label1",
    "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value"
  },
  {
    "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label2",
    "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value2"
  },
  {
    "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label3",
    "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value3"
  },
  {
    "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label4",
    "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value4"
  }
]

let whitespace = new RegExp(/\s/g);
let lo = o.map((entry) => {
  let modified = {};
  Object.keys(entry).forEach((key) => {
    let value = entry[key];
    key = key
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(whitespace, "");
    modified[key] = value;
  });
  return modified;
});

console.log(lo);
```

Comment: replaceAll doesnt work for me as I'm using es2019 lib

Comment: @user18164081 I changed the solution so it uses a regular expression and the normal String.replace method. String.replace should be part of es2019 if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, use `map` function.

```
var arr = [
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label1",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label2",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value2"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label3",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value3"
    },
    {
      "Outdated Label (Key1)": "Outdated Label4",
      "Outdated Value": "Outdated Value4"
    }
  ];

const expectedJson = arr.map(function(item) {
  for(const key of Object.keys(item)) {
    const lowerCaseKey = key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    if (lowerCaseKey !== key) {
      item[lowerCaseKey] = item[key];
      delete item[key];
    }
  }
  return item;
})

console.log(expectedJson)
```

Comment: replaceAll doesnt work for me as I'm using es2019 lib

Comment: @user18164081 changed `replaceAll` to `.replace(/\s/g, '')`.